# Web Api expose specific attribut instead of foreign key

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am new to C# and the Entity Framework and have the following problem.

I have a Player and a Team Model:

```
public class Player
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int TeamID { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

Now I expose the data via rest web api to clients. But when I try to get all players, a json array is returned where the players' team is the ID (foreign key) of the team table. It would be nice, however, to return the team name. How can I achieve that elegantly?

```
{
ID: 7
FirstName: "Sidney"
LastName: "Crosby"
TeamID: 1
}
```

But I would like to have

```
{
ID: 7
FirstName: "Sidney"
LastName: "Crosby"
TeamID: Denver Broncos
}
```

The Web Api Controller looks like:

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetPlayer(int id)
    {
        Player player = await db.Players.FindAsync(id);
        if (player == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(player);
    }
```

Comment: By creating a DTO that contains only the properties of the type you want to return. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314368/to-use-or-not-to-use-data-transfer-objectsdto-in-a-web-api-chat-application-ba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change you player class to reference the parent team instead of just the ID:

```
    public class Player
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
    }
```

Then create a DTO object to expose the properties you want in the structure that you want them:

```
    public class PlayerDto
    {
        public PlayerDto(Player player)
        {
            FirstName = player.FirstName;
            LastName = player.LastName;
            TeamName = player.Team.Name;
        }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string TeamName { get; set; }
    }
```